# I can´t avoid the line break on this column (elementor)

Tags: css, line-breaks, elementor

I have a difficult solution quest here. I'm designing a landing page using elementor. On this specific block i'm using 3 columns  one with the number, one with the line and the last with the text (paragraph) with the text "Sales and marketing director" but I would like to avoid the line break on the marketing director.
The paragraph has a css class rotate_cargo_1 and the only code I have is:

```
.rotate_cargo_1 {transform: rotate(-270deg
);}
```

The live site you can see here
[enter link description here](https://k-explorer.com/launch-event/)

and the section is the "the speakers"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a left margin of `200px` to the text widget, this causes the text to break into separate words as it can't find enough space. Plus that layout involving the number, line and text is positioned absolutely, which is not a good practice.

One hacky method to get around this problem is to set the width of the `div` element wrapping the tagline to something more than 100%.

```
.rotate_cargo_1 div {
   width: 200%;
}
```

However, this is not a good method and can cause overflow issues. A better solution would be to position the elements as static and just make sure that the text has enough space to breathe.

Comment: indeed there is a 200px margin to positioning the text where I'd like to be. I've tried to take tha margin but the text continued to be line broken. But, the DIV width has worked fine! Thanks for your input. About the *absolute, it was used on the text rotation process. Do you have a tip to avoid it? Thanks once again

Comment: Happy to help! Try positioning the elements and then rotate the entire container.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check if it works and let you know